# How to use FastApi and SqlAlchemy for asynchronous operations

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I'm using translation software, there may be some mistakes in expression, please understand
I have checked the tutorials on the internet and followed the corresponding ideas, but I have encountered a little problem, I can't use asynchronous SqlAlchemyc to operate Mysql.

**Database connection**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from urllib import  parse
import  sys

engine = create_async_engine(Sql_URL)


SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine,autocommit=False,autoflush=False)
db_session = scoped_session(SessionLocal)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```

**Models**

```
import asyncio
import datetime

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, DateTime, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry
from  sqlalchemy_utils import EmailType,ChoiceType

from app.Fast_blog.database import Base


class user(Base):
    choices = [
        ('0', 'woman'),
        ('1', 'man'),
        ('2', 'NULL')
    ]
    __tablename__ = "usertable"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    UserId = Column(Integer,primary_key = True,index = True)
    username = Column(String(255))
    userpassword = Column(String(255))
    gender = Column(ChoiceType(choices))
    creation_time = Column(DateTime,default = datetime.datetime.now)
    Last_Login_Time = Column(DateTime,default= datetime.datetime.now)
    UserUuid = Column(String(255))
    UserEmail = Column(EmailType(255))

class Blog(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blogtable"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    title = Column(String(255))
    content = Column(String(255))
    author = Column(String(255))
    BlogId = Column(String(255),primary_key=True,index=True)
    BlogUuid = Column(String(32))
```

**Views**

```
import uuid
from typing import Generator

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_session
from sqlalchemy import select

from app.Fast_blog import model
from app.Fast_blog.model import models
from app.Fast_blog.database.database import engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import EmailStr
from  fastapi import APIRouter

from app.Fast_blog.model.models import user

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=False,bind=engine)
Session = SessionLocal()


UserApp = APIRouter()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="./Fast_blog/templates")

UserApp.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="./Fast_blog/static"), name="static")


def UUID_crt(UuidApi):
    x = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS,UuidApi)
    return x

@UserApp.get("/")
async def query():
    async with Session as session:
        sql = select(model).where(model.id == 1)
        print(sql)
        result = await session.execute(sql)
        data = result.scalars().first()
        # data = result.scalars().all()
```

When I go to test this **def query function**
Then I have a question, is this asynchronous SqlAlchemyc connection a success or a failure? Or is there something wrong with my coding?
it reports an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 404, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\debug.py", line 106, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\debug.py", line 103, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, inner_send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "d:\python3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File ".\Fast_blog\apps\User_app\user.py", line 37, in query
    async with Session as session:
AttributeError: __aenter__
```

Please help me, point out where my code is not correct,I also tried Google. but it doesn't seem to be the same as my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a sync session with this `SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine,autocommit=False,autoflush=False)` but later you try to use it as it were an async session.

I am assuming you are on SQLAlchemy 1.4, if so you need to pass `class_=AsyncSession` as mentioned here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#asyncio-scoped-session

```
from asyncio import current_task
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, async_scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_async_engine(Sql_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False, class_=AsyncSession)
db_session = async_scoped_session(SessionLocal, scopefunc=current_task)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I used your proposal to make changes. Subsequently, I changed the query code to look like this  
```
@UserApp.get("/")
async def query():
    async with db_session() as session:
        sql = select(models.user).where(model.models.id == 1)
```
But he hinted at this error
```
Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got <class 'app.Fast_blog.model.models.user'>.

```

Comment: if it works can you accept the answer @Exploit? and no prob regarding the misunderstanding

Comment: I have some more questions, please see the above questions, because my network problems, may be a little delayed response

Comment: you are asking an entirely different question now, I will try to help but you have to show your code @Exploit I am not able to figure out what is `model` and `models`

Comment: from app.Fast_blog.database.database import db_session
from app.Fast_blog.model import models

Main Code
![MY2Fk.jpeg](https://i.328888.xyz/2023/03/19/MY2Fk.jpeg)
Database Models
![MYrcy.jpeg](https://i.328888.xyz/2023/03/19/MYrcy.jpeg)

Comment: sql = select(models.user).where(models.user.UserEmail == 1)
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression, FROM clause, or other columns clause element expected, got <class 'app.Fast_blog.model.models.user'>.  
It prompts an error like this

Comment: `class user(Base)` you just have `class user()` does changing that work?

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it works fine now. Your help was very helpful for my first time learning.